# Kentico - Global.asax file issue after publishing

Tags: kentico, global-asax

I have installed a new Kentico web application and I can browse the site without any problem. This site is hosted in IIS, Now I want to add some customization and created another web application application using MVC and registering routes etc in application start of global.asax event.

Kentico project also has a global.asax file and it contains some code logic.

[image] When I publish my custom web project, It overwrites the existing default Kentico global.asax with global file from my application and application breaks.

[image]
Is there any way to have a 2 different global.asax file in a web application with different names? I want both global files should execute separately.

Comment: Please don't mix MVC & Web forms in a single solution/web site... Also Kentico's MVC is supposed to be a separate application completely as you can find out here: https://docs.kentico.com/k11/developing-websites/developing-sites-using-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't believe you can do that.  What you can do is publish your MVC site to an application in IIS instead.  You might find the following article from Kentico helpful: [Creating virtual directories and application pools in IIS 7.5 and 7.0](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/installation/deploying-kentico-to-a-live-server/creating-virtual-directories-and-application-pools-in-iis-7-5-and-7-0)